# Why declare an array this way

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking at code written by someone else and it declares an array this way (which I think is still a string, can someone confirm).

```
$array = "Label 1" . "~/" . "Label 2" . "~/" . "Label 3" . "~/" . "Label4";
```

Then later in the code, it does this

```
split('~/', $array);
```

Is there a valid reason why anyone would do it this way? I would normally declare it as an array from the start.

Comment: Seem it an obfuscation script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is absolutely no defendable reason to do things this way instead of just

```
$array = Array("Label 1", ... , "Label 4");
```

In fact it's a very bad way of doing it, unless you can guarantee that the string `"~/"` will never appear in the array's elements.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I could think of someone doing this is if they want to later save `$array` to a text file, for example save some application settings to a php file. But they would still have been better to define an array the usual way and then use implode, as others have already mentioned this is still not the best idea and has problems.

Answer (score 3):

In variable $array, it's still a string, just like this:

```
$array = "Label 1~/Label 2~/Label 3~/Label4";
```

But after it do something like

```
$realArray = split("~/",$array);
```

It will become an array.

If someone who know how to create an array doing this, I would guess that he/she wants to save this string for use later. But a better way to do this is

```
$array = array("Label 1","Label 2","Label 3","Label 4");
$string = implode("~/",$array);
```

So, just forget it and use the normal way.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the context I can't be definitive, but doing it like this as you've posted there is no obvious benefit.

It's inefficient, as it uses multiple extra steps (variable assignment, string iteration and array population).

The most efficient way to do this would be:

`$array = array( "Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4" );`

This would have the same result.

Answer (score 2):

It's a horrible way to do it.

- It's not immediately obvious what the code does, over an `array()` definition which would be recognised immediately.
- [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is deprecated.
- You need to remember that "~/" is *magic*.
- String concatenation for readability in a code *style* that hinders readability.

Really, you should drop that and use `array('Label 1', ...)`.